# What is the best place to configure a MongoDB connection in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, dependency-injection

Another MVC framework I've used - Symfony2 - uses a dependency injector to carefully configure and manage dependencies.

Does ASP.NET MVC have anything similar which would let me configure a MongoDB connection and then pass it down to my controller logic where it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different dependency injection libraries you can use with Asp.net MVC, here's a (non comprehensive) list:

- StructureMap
- Ninject
- Autofac
- Unity
- Spring.net.

If you go looking for them in Nuget, typically there will be one package for the container itself, and a different package that adds the Asp.Net MVC plugins.

Take a look at them, figure out which flavor you like, then configure your mongo db connection to be per-request,  add the connection to your controller constructor, and away you go.  If you pick a lib and update your question, I'm sure someone will answer with specific code etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally done in the web.config file

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="MONGOHQ_URL" value="mongodb://localhost/YourDBName"/>
 </appSettings>
```

The value can be referenced like this...

```
public class ConfigEnvironment
   {
      public static string GetConnectionString()
      {
         return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MONGOHQ_URL") ??
                "mongodb://localhost";
      }
   }
```

Use this to create your database

```
MongoDatabase.Create(ConfigEnvironment.GetConnectionString())
```

Comment: This stores connection information, but not the instance itself it seems.